# How to identify correctly between 3/4 and 4/4 strumming patterns?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, acoustic-guitar, guitar-effects, strumming

I am new to guitar and confused between strumming patterns. I know that 4/4 have 4 beats in it and 3/4 have 3 beats in it.
I can't differentiate between them, e.g :
3/4 : D DUDU D DUDU
4/4 : D D UUDUD DU or DDUU DU DDUU DU or D UDUD UDUD DU
how can I learn to correctly identify between them (if a strumming pattern is written in U's and D's form), whether it is 3/4 or 4/4 pattern?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking, but I think that the difference you are looking for has to do with where accents are placed. In 4/4 time the "one" and the "three" get the accents, with the "one" slightly stronger: **ONE** two THREE four.... This differs from 2/4 time: **ONE** two **ONE** two.... In 3/4 time the "one" gets the accent: **ONE** two three....

Comment: I didn't learn the music theory, but what I am asking is, if someone writes down a strumming pattern to me in form of U's and D's, then how do i identify whether it's 3/4 or 4/4 in general.

Comment: "e.g : 3/4 : D DUDU D DUDU" -- there really isn't enough information in a strumming pattern like this to be able to assign a time signature to it. This could be 3/4: **ONE** two & three & **ONE** two & three &, or it could be 4/4 if the first D corresponds to a whole note and the DUDU corresponds to four quarter notes. Strumming patterns carry very little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work out the time signature by attempting the following:

- Listening to where the first beat of each bar is - usually, this is apparent by listening to the drumkit or by feeling where each bar starts. As long as you can figure out **ONE** ????? **ONE** ?????, where the question marks are the beats in between, that's the first step.
- Once you've worked this out, you can count how many beats are in between. Is it **ONE** two three **ONE** two three, or **ONE** two three four **ONE** two three four?

Try to ignore what the guitar is doing when you're working out the time signature. Non-boring guitar is all about rhythmic embellishments (something like `D DUDU` instead of just `D D D` in 3/4), which can be distracting. Working out music is easiest when you strip away all of the embellishments and complexity, and just focus on the bare-bones of the song. You can work out all of the intricacies later.

Answer (score 3):

Use a very basic DDDD for 4/4 and DDD for 3/4. The first D will often be more emphasised. So, if you hear the 4th D louder, it's because it's 3/4!

Sort out about U later. Let's face it, after each and every D there's going to be an U in order to strum D again...And, remember, the Ds are the basic 1234 (or123) in each bar/measure.

Those U can be put in whenever and wherever you like, but beware of the U just before a chord change. So many self taught guitarists strum U with open strings as they can't change the chord quick enough, and it is so amateur.